# Overlaying a normal curve on a histogram with discrete values

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to create a histogram with a normal curve overlayed. I have found a lot of good advice as to how to do this here and elsewhere but for some reason, I am still missing something because the normal curve ends up being flat at the bottom.

For some background, participants were asked to rate a number of items on a 1-6 scale and I am attempting to plot how frequently they used each rating on the scale. The data includes discrete values which I think may also be contributing to making the plots a bit trickier. Here is a sample of the original data:

```
structure(list(item = c("beads_1", "beads_2", "notebook_1", "notebook_2", 
"notebook_3", "notebook_4"), values = c(3L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 4L
), pid = c("5fb030143a5ee13bad82db81", "5fb030143a5ee13bad82db81", 
"5fb030143a5ee13bad82db81", "5fb030143a5ee13bad82db81", "5fb030143a5ee13bad82db81", 
"5fb030143a5ee13bad82db81"), age = c(25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 
25L), sex = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), bapq = c(3.166666667, 
3.166666667, 3.166666667, 3.166666667, 3.166666667, 3.166666667
), item_run = c(1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L)), row.names = c(NA, 6L
), class = "data.frame")
```

I basically used the code below to get counts for each of the ratings:

```
unique.rate <- sort(unique(adu_pref2$values))
count <- table(adu_pref2$values)
count.rate <- data.frame(unique.rate, count)
count.rate <- count.rate[, -c(2)]
```

This generates a small dataframe with the discrete values and frequency of those ratings:

```
structure(list(unique.rate = 1:6, Freq = c(2095L, 2905L, 5059L, 
8413L, 6666L, 3540L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
```

With this dataframe, I created a histogram using the code below:

```
adu_plot <- ggplot(count.rate, aes(unique.rate, Freq, fill=unique.rate, width = 1))

adu_plot + geom_bar(stat="identity") + 
        labs(y="Frequency", x="Rating") + 
        theme(legend.position="none") + stat_function(
    fun = dnorm, 
    args = list(count.rate, mean = mean(count.rate$Freq), sd = sd(count.rate$Freq)), 
    color = "red", 
    size = 1.2)
```

This creates a figure that has the histogram configured correctly but not the normal curve overlay. How do I resolve this issue?
[image]

Comment: FYI, the calculated `count.rate` has 3 rows, your sample has 6, something is being lost in the sampling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you change from `fun=` to `fun=function(...) { browser(); dnorm(...); }` to see what's going on. When you again plot it, look at the arguments passed to it:

```r
ggplot(count.rate, aes(unique.rate, Freq, fill=unique.rate, width = 1)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity") + 
           labs(y="Frequency", x="Rating") + 
           theme(legend.position="none") + 
  stat_function(
      fun = function(...) { browser(); dnorm(...); }, 
      args = list(count.rate, mean = mean(count.rate$Freq), sd = sd(count.rate$Freq)), 
      color = "red", 
      size = 1.2)

list(...)
# [[1]]
#   [1] 1.00 1.05 1.10 1.15 1.20 1.25 1.30 1.35 1.40 1.45 1.50 1.55 1.60 1.65 1.70 1.75 1.80 1.85 1.90 1.95 2.00 2.05 2.10 2.15 2.20 2.25 2.30 2.35 2.40 2.45 2.50 2.55 2.60 2.65 2.70 2.75 2.80 2.85 2.90 2.95 3.00 3.05 3.10 3.15 3.20 3.25 3.30 3.35 3.40 3.45 3.50 3.55 3.60 3.65 3.70 3.75 3.80 3.85 3.90 3.95 4.00 4.05 4.10
#  [64] 4.15 4.20 4.25 4.30 4.35 4.40 4.45 4.50 4.55 4.60 4.65 4.70 4.75 4.80 4.85 4.90 4.95 5.00 5.05 5.10 5.15 5.20 5.25 5.30 5.35 5.40 5.45 5.50 5.55 5.60 5.65 5.70 5.75 5.80 5.85 5.90 5.95 6.00
# [[2]]
#   unique.rate Freq
# 1           1 2095
# 2           2 2905
# 3           3 5059
# 4           4 8413
# 5           5 6666
# 6           6 3540
# $mean
# [1] 4780
# $sd
# [1] 2412
```

Note how there are *four* arguments, and the first (your `count.rate`) is being passed to [`dnorm`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/Normal.html) as its `log=` (getting your `count.rate` frame, which is possibly interpreted as `log=TRUE`, not entirely sure but it doesn't really matter). Note that `ggplot2` is already adding in the `x=` values so that it can get the `y` values returned (in order to plot its x against the returned y).

(You can "Q" of the debugger now :-)

Ultimately, the problem is that you are calculating the mean/sd of the frequency counts themselves and not on the underlying `unique.rate` values. I suggest you try them instead. (I'll also scale it so that it reaches the top of the max `count.rate$Freq`.)

```r
ggplot(count.rate, aes(unique.rate, Freq, fill=unique.rate, width = 1)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity") + 
           labs(y="Frequency", x="Rating") + 
           theme(legend.position="none") + 
  stat_function(
      fun = function(...) { y <- dnorm(...); max(count.rate$Freq) * y/max(y); },
      args = list(mean = mean(count.rate$unique.rate), sd = sd(count.rate$unique.rate)), 
      color = "red", 
      size = 1.2)
```

[image: ggplot barplot with normal curve]

I recognize though that `unique.rate` may or may not be a continuous (enough) variable, over to you for interpretation if it is ordinal or nominal.

Comment: This is a very helpful answer! I am noticing that the normal curve is mostly at the top half of the plot. Am I right in thinking that this is a result of the scaling?

Comment: (1) Yes the scale, but more of a factor is that (2) ggplot gave it `x` values based on the range of the x-axis, which in this case is between 1 and 6. If you want it to include values beyond that, you can add (say) `xlim=c(0,7)` to the `stat_function` call and expand it out a little, though that will also add blank space to either side of the bars.

Comment: Note that if I'm interpreting your data correctly, you are using a symmetric and continuous distribution on _counting_ data, which does not have negative values and therefore cannot be normally distributed. You might find a better distributional match using Poisson or Negative Binomial or other distributions that are good for counting problems (i.e., discrete, no negatives, etc). See [Why is Poisson regression used for count data?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/3024/60634).